# Restore Apache Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, restore

can anyone please tell me how to restore an apache configuration from backup ? from /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.backup

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you have the .backup file. All you need to do is :

```
cp /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf.backup /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf
```

Then restart your apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Move the current config into another backup file (httpd.conf.backup2)

```
mv /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.backup2
```

Move the original backup back into place

```
mv /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.backup /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Restart apache

```
apache2ctl restart
```